# Can't find Google Apps Script project in docs list in Google Drive, Android or desktop

Tags: google-apps-script

This page: http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.de/2012/06/apps-script-in-docs-list.html
 says

Google Apps Script projects are now included in the docs list in Google Drive.
- Your projects are now stored in Google Drive and can be shared just like any other file.

Well, it ain't working for me. I can get the app working by following the link
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyAo3y-3... but I can't see it listed in Google Drive, neither in the desktop arr nor Android. I want to access it by clicking on an item in the list because I want to get to it on my mobile, can't be typing those long random URLS.

When I look at Google Drive on the desktop, and search under "Owner, Type, More>>", it doesn't even show anything remotely Web App like in the list.

Comment: Now you can use [Apps Script Dashboard](https://script.google.com/home) according to a newer answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Today, 2018-1-11, Google launched the [Apps Script Dashboard](https://script.google.com/home). It list all the script project files, standalone and bounded.

Reference

- [3 new tools to help improve your Apps Script development and management experience](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2018/01/three-new-tools-to-help-improve-your.html)

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid there is a small misunderstanding here... the script itself can be created as a standalone document in the drive's doclist, not the executable macro, these are two different things.

What you refer to is an url that points to the server and starts the execution of a script.  What the documentation says is that the script (which is an editable text file after all) doesn't need to be included in a site or in a spreadsheet but can exist as a new document type.

Sorry for being redundant but I wanted to be sure it was clear enough.

**EDIT** (following your comment) : you are right : if you created the script in a spreadsheet "container" it doesn't appear as a standalone script file. It does only if you create it independently.
That said, I think the easiest way to have fast access to webapp is to create a shortcut in the Browser itself, a so called ***bookmark*** or ***favorite*** (depending of your Browser)... at least this is how I do :-)

And it's not an issue to send such a link by email since you don't have to type it ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

OK, shame I can't get a list of my GAS Web Apps under Google Drive, but regardless - I can't find the script under Google Drive either. Perhaps because I created it from a spreadsheet? But if I create a Web App script from inside a Spreadsheet, the Project doesn't know anything about the spreadsheet (I have to use openById to access the Spreadsheet) but the script only exists within the Spreadsheet? Weird.

So back to my original problem - how do access a public Web App I create on another computer, is there an easy way without having to send long unwieldy links around?

Comment: Thanks, I understand, it seems odd not to treat Web Apps as presentation or drawings, but there you go.

Comment: that's ridiculous that you need to add as favorite / bookmark to find script. This is basic functionality.

Comment: New answer below is to use [Apps Script Dashboard](https://script.google.com/home)

Answer (score 1):

First open up a new Google script at https://script.google.com.

From there, you can click **File --> Open...**. This will bring up Google Drive in a window, but with the special search already in the search box: "**type:script**".

You can go directly to it here: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/search?q=type:script

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question, and I would like to direct you guys to [this link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) in the docs that explains the difference between a bound and an unbound script. I found a great script that someone shared and I wanted to make a backup of it, but could not find it in Google Drive even after saving his spreadsheet that was using the script. Turns out it was a bound script, and that is perfectly normal.

So I am either going to create a new project and copy and paste the script, OR maybe do it right by making another copy of it that will hopefully show up in all my sheets when I go to Tools>Script Editor.

(Edit) I copied and pasted the code into a new project. But before I did that:

1. I opened the spreadsheet that I wanted to run the script on.
2. Went to Tools>Script Editor, and made a new project (since the copy of the script still didn't show up in my projects list).
3. Copied and pasted the script into my new project.
4. Run>onOpen to run the script! It works!