# search *somewhere* (Google Drive?) for Google Apps Script that contain search terms

Tags: google-apps-script

I have many GAS that are *bound* to Google Sheets. I need to find the ones that reference certain search terms (FWIW, we're restructuring our BigQuery tables and I need to find out which ones reference the old table names so we can update them).

I've tried searching for the term in Google Drive without success.
I've tried to search for the term in the [Apps Script Dashboard](https://script.google.com/), but that only let's you search for project names.
And I did try to search in the Apps Script Dashboard using "type:script", but that doesn't let me search for any bound-script names, let along the *contents* of any bound scripts.

Is there a way to find/identify the scripts that reference "search term"?

Just as an example, if a bound script contains this code:   *var projectId = 'company-inventory';*

I would like to be able to find that script by searching for "company-inventory".

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11568898/1595451, https://stackoverflow.com/q/18012446/1595451

Comment: @Rubén thank you. I did come across that link and it didn't help. I edited my question with more details. Hopefully it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api)

- It features the method [projects.getContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent) that allows you to retrieve the content of an Apps Script with a known id programatically
- You can programatically search within each retrieved project content for your key word
- You can previously query for the ids of standalone script files with the Google Drive API [list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) setting the [q](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files) parameter to `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.script'`
- Unfortunately the same does not apply for bound scripts - you can only retrieve the ids of those scripts from the Apps Script Dashboard

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of files to go through. Thanks, I'll give this a shot!

Comment: Is there a request to Google to provide search insight to bound scripts? I am maintaining my own index in a spreadsheet but as the number of scripts I build increases this is very onerous.