# Can I see if there is a google apps script attached to a document I download from Google Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a link to a Google Drive thrugh which I download certain things.
I would like to know if there is a way to specifically see if a file has a google apps script bound to a document I download from the drive.

I'll add that I have editor privileges to the files.

Thanks!

I tried asking chatGPT and Bard. GPT says it doesn't find any info, Bard seems to make up some stuff. I want a more conclusive answer.

Comment: Have you read [Can't find Google Apps Script project in docs list in Google Drive, Android or desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48218582/1330560)

Answer (score 0):

I guess an easy solution is to go to the menu > Extensions (next to help), then select app scripts. When the page opens, if it called "untitled", and the only script you can see is called

function myFunction() {

}

Then there is no script attached to it.

Cheers Mads